# Changing the linux process scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduler

I have a task (OS course) of changing the linux process scheduler (compiling the kernel with different schedulers in virtual machine) and then to write multi-threaded program and benchmark the program on each scheduler.

However, I tried to find information regarding how to change the default scheduler from CFS to RR or FIFO, but couldn't find (found only real-time scheduler change, but I was told that it's preferred for the task to compile different kernels with different schedulers).

What am I missing? How could this be done? It is my first time working on the kernel, let alone compiling a kernel.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: https://aelseb.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/change-linux-cpu-default-scheduler/ Seems relevant.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23049466/1216776